# How to use elasticsearch for indexing formulas in MathML?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, mathjax, mathml

I have a Q&A website that use Elasticsearch on it and also use MathML to type formulas. For example

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>d</mi>
    <mi>e</mi>
    <mi>t</mi>
    <mo> </mo>
    <mi>A</mi>
    <mo>≠</mo>
    <mn>0</mn>
</math>
```

is the MathML code for `det A ≠ 0`.

the problem is that elasticsearch is indexing it like a simple text(not formula), so the result of searching "det" is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MathML is not semantically correct for what you are doing.  It doesn't mean `det A ≠ 0`, but rather `d * e * t A ≠ 0`; that is the product of `d`, `e`, and `t` followed by `A ≠ 0` (I'm not sure what the empty `<mo>` represents, but the space is ignored by MathML.)

A better representation would be

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>det</mi>
    <mo>&#x2061;</mo>
    <mi>A</mi>
    <mo>≠</mo>
    <mn>0</mn>
</math>
```

That might resolve your issue with searching as well, since now `det` will match something.

Comment: Thank you, it was so helpful.